# Structure pointer member pointing to another structure leads to segmentation fault (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure

I get segmentation fault when a structure member points to another structure. In details, my new structure is

```
typedef struct _sock_t{
  ir_socket_t *_socket;
  bool flag;
  extern_class obj;
  double *vect;
};
```

while the structure I want to point to is `ir_socket_t socket;`. In `main()`, if I do something like

```
  _sock_t *_sock ;
  _sock->_socket = &socket;
```

I then get segmentation fault. However,

```
  _sock_t _sock ;
  _sock._socket = &socket;
```

works fine. What is wrong about the first approach.

P.S. Note that `ir_socket_t` is C not C++ structure.

---

UPDATE:
 If I also consider a C++ class object as new a structure member, then I still get segmentation fault at

```
int n(4);
_sock->obj.resize(4); // here segmentation fault
```

while there is no problem with the latter approach (no pointer). This happens even if I do `_sock_t *_sock = (_sock_t *)malloc(sizeof(_sock_t));`; using @Bathshebba answer.

What could be the issue please?

Note that `_sock->vect= new double[n]` works fine.

Note also that  `_sock = new _sock_t;` works instead fine.

Comment: You haven't initialized `_sock`.

Comment: `_sock_t *_sock`. You better learn about pointers before you proceed any further with your C programming. That's an uninitalised pointer and of course you can't dereference it.

Comment: The variable `_sock` is not initialized to point to a valid (properly allocated) memory block.

Comment: Please don't downvote on the grounds of obviousness. This question, IMHO, is well written.

Comment: It's the difference between a *pointer* object  and a *struct* object. `_sock_t *_sock ;` defines a *pointer* object which doesn't point anywhere; if you try to access the object "it points to" with`_sock->_socket`(quotes because it doesn't), you segfault. By contrast, `_sock_t _sock ;` defines an object of type `_sock_t` which has an existing  field `_sock._socket`.

Answer (score 2):

That's hardly surprising. In writing `_sock_t *_sock` all you've done is declare a pointer.

But it doesn't *point* to anything. The behaviour on *dereferencing* it (in your case via the pointer to member operator `->`) is *undefined*.

You need to point it at allocated memory. Use `malloc` for this in C, and `new` in C++. Don't forget to call `free` and `delete` respectively once you're done with the pointer, else you'll *leak* memory.

Finally, (acknowledge @Karthick), it appears you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code: in C you'd need to write `struct _sock_t *_sock;`.

Comment: The word "type" is redundant IMO.

Comment: @barakmanos: yes, I think you're correct; it does read better without it.

Comment: I already tried `_sock_t *_sock=NULL`, but without success. Should I try `_sock_t *_sock = malloc(sizeof(_sock_t));`?

Comment: Absolutely! Don't forget to call `free` once you're done with `_sock`.

Comment: `_sock_t *_sock ;` Is this statement valid ? Since typedef is used in structure this statement might not be valid.

Comment: If this is a C++-question (it's tagged as such), you shouldn't be using `malloc`

Comment: Well, `ir_socket_t` is pure C, while  `_sock_t` is defined in C++ code.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I just have updated my question. There is still one problem...